# Test react native firebase push notification in simulator

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, push-notification

According to the react native firebase doc, the push notification does not work in simulator.
Even Out-of-app notifications (when app is in background and you see the notification in the status bar) does not work when you run the app on your real ios/Android device connected to your PC by cable. (In-app notifications work though using `messaging().onMessage`)

**Current behavior**:
My Firebase push notification works perfectly on both Android and ios in standalone apk/ipa.
However, I cannot test it during development on simulator.

**Desired behavior**:
I want to receive push notification (Out-of-app notification) when the app is running on simulator in background, so that I can use `messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp` method as usual.

**Why I need this?**
Of course, each time I make a change regarding push notification, I can create a standalone app, install it on phone to see how it works.
This approach has many issues:

1. It's super time-consuming and does not  make sense at all
2. If the code does not work as expected, there is no way to check what goes wrong
3. There is no `console.log`, in general, no way to debug the code

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking from us here. If this feature is documented to not work on `react-native-firebase`, shouldn't this be a feature request on that [repo](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase)?

Comment: Dear @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for your reply. I wanted to know if there is a trick for doing this.

Comment: Did you found any way to test react native firebase push notifications on simulator? I am struggling so bad, please suggest if you have any solution.

Comment: Dear @ArchanaSharma, after four months I have not found any solution to this. I can understand how frustrating it is when it comes to testing your system, it just super time-consuming. Unfortunately, Xcode simulators do not support this.

Answer (score 4):

For firebase's `messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp` to be triggered I used the following payload json:

```json
{
  "Simulator Target Bundle": "bundle.identifier",
  "google.c.a.e": 1,
  "foo": "bar",
  "aps": {
      "alert": "Alert!",
      "content-available": 1
  },
  "gcm.message_id": "0:1538488916770554%a88db343a88db34"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally, you can do this in Xcode 11.4 and later ([Release note](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-11_4-release-notes)).

> Simulator supports simulating remote push notifications, including
> background content fetch notifications.

Also [here](https://www.daily-coding.net/posts/expo-4-steps-to-run-push-on-ios-simulator) you can find a step-by-step guide to do that, based on react native.

Comment: Can you confirm that this will work on `bare-workflow (NOT expo managed-workflow) react-native ` project?

Comment: Yes, it's about an Xcode feature. but you should understand that it doesn't work with `react-native-firebase` functions like `getInitialNotification()` at this time. Maybe in the future, this team decide to release some more details about the ios simulator push. It can be good if you create an issue on `react-native-firebase` till they use this Xcode feature as soon as possible.